Jupyter hub server spawn timeout
I use a Jupyterhub to access a supercomputer using singularity to perform HPC. Since yesterday my request to spawn a new server timeout all the time.
The only log that I have are :
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:51.404 ServerApp] Extension package jupyter_server_fileid to
ok 0.1206s to import
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:51.985 ServerApp] Extension package jupyter_server_proxy too
k 0.5802s to import
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:52.178 ServerApp] Extension package jupyter_server_terminals
 took 0.1928s to import
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.176 ServerApp] Extension package jupyter_server_ydoc took
 0.9974s to import
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.460 ServerApp] Extension package jupyterlab took 0.2836s 
to import
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.681 ServerApp] Extension package jupyterlab_jupytext took
 0.1601s to import
[W 2024-04-11 13:48:53.746 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` funct
ion was not found in nbclassic. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` fun
ction was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated 
in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.754 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was succ
essfully linked.
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.754 ServerApp] jupyter_server_proxy | extension was succe
ssfully linked.
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.758 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was s
uccessfully linked.
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.764 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was succes
sfully linked.
[I 2024-04-11 13:48:53.764 JupyterHubSingleUser] Starting jupyterhub single-user
 server extension version 4.0.2
[E 2024-04-11 13:48:53.764 JupyterHubSingleUser] Failed to load JupyterHubSingle
User server extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/extens
ion.py", line 274, in wrapped
        r = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/extens
ion.py", line 472, in load_config_file
        raise KeyError("Missing required environment $JUPYTERHUB_SERVICE_URL")
    KeyError: 'Missing required environment $JUPYTERHUB_SERVICE_URL'


The only changes I've made are trying to install :
$ pip install jupyterlab-nvdashboard

$ jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-nvdashboard

From https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-dashboards-in-jupyter-lab/. However the second installation failed as Node.js is not installed and I have pip uninstall jupyterlab-nvdashboard since.
The both installation of JupyterHub and JupyterHubSingleUser are 4.1.5.
The person in charge of these issues is on holiday. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?
